# Magento 2 Elasticsearch security problem

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch, magento2.4

When i in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` setting this code:

```
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
```

and already set user and password , it can on Browser loading http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200 and then success enter user and password.

But i go back to magento backend to set back the info, it was showing `No alive nodes found in your cluster setup` , where i getting wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you ping your elastic search IP from your server?

Comment: Yes i in command ping after showing PING XX.XX.XX.XX (XX.XX.XX.XX) 56(84) bytes of data. @BartZalas

Comment: So check with curl on elastic search instance is it running on this port.

Comment: yes, but it is need user name and password. @BartZalas

Comment: curl --user your user:pass